# Rync connection problems from Windows to CentOS

Tags: windows, centos, rsync, cygwin

Trying to connect to rsync on CentOS from Cygwin on Windows 7 but getting the following errors:

```
$ rsync -vrtz -vvv --password-file=c:\cygwin\secret --delete /cygdrive/d/Data username@xx.xx.xx.xx::modulename

opening tcp connection to xx.xx.xx.xx port 873
rsync: failed to connect to xx.xx.xx.xx (xx.xx.xx.xx): Connection timed out (116)
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=10, file=/home/lapo/package/rsync-3.0.9-1/src/rsync-3.0.9/clientserver.c, line=122): entered
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at /home/lapo/package/rsync-3.0.9-1/src/rsync-3.0.9/clientserver.c(122) [sender=3.0.9]
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=10, file=/home/lapo/package/rsync-3.0.9-1/src/rsync-3.0.9/clientserver.c, line=122): about to call exit(10)
```

I can SSH to this server from putty on the same windows machine. I can ping the IP address directly as well.

Do I need to ensure that a specific port is open for rsync to connect on?

**Update**

Doing

```
cat /etc/services | grep rsync
```

Returns

```
rsync           873/tcp                         # rsync
rsync           873/udp                         # rsync
```

**Another update**

iptables -L

outputs:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
           tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ftp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ftp

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp any
ACCEPT     esp  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     ah   --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251         udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Comment: It's saying connection timed out. Is `rsync` running as a daemon on the remote node, and is there any firewall running?

Comment: rsync is running on remote. How can I ensure it is running as a daemon? I am checking on the port issue but I am not sure how to check if that port is open to traffic. Bit of a server newbie.

Comment: made some updates above to show the output of firewall and port listening settings. what am I missing?

Comment: It looks like netfilter is blocking port 873. Try running `service iptables stop` briefly and see if it works, if it does, I'll add an answer with the fix.

Comment: boo ya. Connection worked. There were other errors but I think just in my rsync config which I will try to work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the default `netfilter` ruleset running on your CentOS server.

If this host is internal-only (not publicly-accessible) you could disable the firewall:

```
service iptables stop
chkconfig iptables off
```

However, it would be better to simply allow the rsync port:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 873 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
```